# console log for js function showing undefined

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-events

I am trying to print the function and see in `console.log`,
but I am not sure whether I am doing it correctly,
since when I print it in `console.log` it show undefined.

The function I am going to print is `coffeeDisplay`.

```
songApply : function () {
            roseDisplay.menu(_g('div-id'));
            shopLoadIndication = true;
            roseDisplay.coffeeDisplay();
            console.log(roseDisplay.coffeeDisplay());
            kiteUp.knowOther(0, 0);

coffeeDisplay : function(){
            var upDown =  _g("scs-id");
            var reSpan = Ptil.Style.g('sc-disply-trim', upDown, 'div')[0];
            var reAll = Ptil.Style.g('sc-li', upDown, 'li');
            var html = "";
            var noHtml = "";
            var ckAll = 0;
            var l = reAll.length;
            for(var i=0;i<l;i++){
                if (Ptil.Style.ccss(reAll[i], "add-other-li")) {
                    break;
                }
                if(Ptil.gc(reAll[i],0).checked){
                    ckAll++;
                    if(html!==""){html+=";  ";noHtml+="|";}
                    html+=Ptil.gc(reAll[i],1).innerHTML;
                    noHtml+= Ptil.gc(reAll[i],3).innerHTML + "," + Ptil.gc(reAll[i],2).innerHTML;
                }
            }
            if(html===""){html=i18n.NO_sc_SELECTED;}
            html+='<img align="middle" src="../img/5322_down.png"><span class="selected-scs hidden">' + noHtml + '</span><div id="display-trim-list-image-id" class="display-trim-list-image hidden"><img align="middle" src="../img/5322_down.png"></div>';
            reSpan.innerHTML = html;
            //Check to see if more than 1 selected sc, then disable the Timeline.
            if(ckAll>1){    
                orklist.disableTimeline();      
            }
        }
```

Comment: Does coffeeDisplay() return a value?

Comment: We don't know enough about your code, but if the console is showing undefined, it means you haven't defined whatever you're trying to print to the console.

Comment: You are logging the **result** of the function.  Are you trying to log the function itself?

Comment: Provide the code for coffeeDisplay() please.

Comment: @Mr.Web: thanks for your reply providing my code updated my coffeeDisplay function

Comment: Looks like the songApply function is missing a closing brace and comma at the end. This should be a syntax error.

Comment: @JoeFrambach: thanks for your reply...i am not asking abt that error since i posted only half function

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to print the function on the console, you should do it like

```
console.log(roseDisplay.coffeeDisplay)
```

Right now, you are logging the return value of *roseDisplay.coffeeDisplay* which is undefined.

Comment: thanks for your reply now if i use it in the firebug window its shows function()  when i hover over it it shows null

Comment: I am sorry, i don't know why it can be null. Only thing that comes to my mind is that function might not be defined. But then it should have showed undefined instead of null.

Answer (score 0):

I would pull up your browsers debugger and step through it, it sounds to me like your function coffeeDisplay just doesn't return any value so logging the result will only give you undefined.